# How do I tell if an internet url points to a folder or a file using HttpWebRequest in C#?

Tags: c#

It should be well known that a internet URL can point to either a folder or a file.
A folder usually responds with a default page -- e.g. index.html.
A file responds with itself.

In either case, you don't know which one you are getting. Imagine for instance ("http://www.example.com/fileorfolder.html"). Is it an oddly named folder that is returning a default file or is it a file?

How do I tell?

Comment: maybe this would help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1395205/better-way-to-check-if-path-is-a-file-or-a-directory-c-net

Comment: the web doesn't have folders, just urls that point to resources.

Comment: Ok... but because I need to build a localized simulation of any given website, I need to determine ("address bar speaking") the "map" of it, regardless of what one calls the areas of a site.

Comment: So what you're really asking isn't how to determine if something is a "folder" or a "file," but rather how to determine the hierarchical structure of some Web site. I know of no other way than to crawl the site and keep track of the URLs, then parse the segments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may be best to check if you are redirected from the requested URL to a different URL.

Check out this link.

[C# detect page redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538895/c-sharp-detect-page-redirect)

Answer (score 3):

Your assumption is wrong - (outside of WebDAV) there are no "folders" or "files" on the web, only arbitrary resources.

If a web server is configured to map a resource path to a filesystem (as most, *but not all*, are by default) then accessing a "folder" still returns a HTML document, only the document contains a listing of files - but the format of this document varies depending on the software used.

Why are you wanting to know anyway?