# Unable to fetch httpwebresponse for a particular site

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I am trying do get response from this site(http://www.citizensbank.com/) but i am unable to achieve it. There is an exception saying operation timed out. Even i increase the timeout to 30 mins.

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://www.citizensbank.com");
        request.Timeout = 30000;
        HttpWebResponse response;

        try
        {
            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            return response.ResponseUri;
        }
```

My question is, does the site somehow prevent to get the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you browse `http://www.citizensbank.com` you will get redirected to the `https` version.
Trying your code with `https` works.

That means the website redirects the requests to the secure site.

In most cases the code should work with the redirect since `request.AllowAutoRedirect` is `true` by default, but it does not and hangs, that means that probably someone only redirects request from browsers.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2538895/c-sharp-detect-page-redirect) questions shows how to identify redirects, but it does not work for this site.