# define a web request for the specified URL

Tags: c#, asp.net

what is the best way to validate a valid url and through error message?

i am using something like this:

```
 HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
```

i am doing try and catch to catch the error message

is that enough or can be do better then that?

Comment: I believe you are doing it right. Here is a question which has already been asked: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924679/c-how-can-i-check-if-a-url-exists-is-valid   You can use the WebResponse to check your URL

Comment: Validate that the URL is valid uri syntax?  Or validate that URL points to an actual valid location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see if you get a response from that URL you have to -

```
WebResponse webResponse = req.GetResponse();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regular expressions (System.Text.RegularExpressions namespace) to test for valid URLs:

```
var urlTester = new Regex( @"http(s)?://([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+(/[\w- ./?%&=]*)?" );
bool isValidUrl = urlTester.IsMatch( url );
```

Also ask google for other Regex URL patterns if it's needed.