# Detect image source exists using ImageResizer's RemoteReader plugin and generate tiny url

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, imageresizer

I'm using [ImageResizer](http://imageresizing.net/)'s [RemoteReader plugin](http://imageresizing.net/plugins/remotereader) to show the external images in my site.

I have 2 problems:

1- When I generate image source path using `RemoteReaderPlugin.Current.CreateSignedUrl` method, it returns an encoded url like [this](http://www.mysite.com/remote.jpg.ashx?width=100&height=100&mode=carve&carve=true&urlb64=aHR0cDovL3VwbG9hZC53aWtpbWVkaWEub3JnL3dpa2lwZWRpYS9jb21tb25zL2UvZWUvQ2hhcmxlc19FdmFuc19IdWdoZXNfY3BoLjNiMTU0MDEuanBn&hmac=FREsrz7xR5E). As you see the url is so long, is there any option that I can generate a smaller url (like what [TinyUrl](http://tinyurl.com/) and [goo.gl](http://goo.gl/) do)?

2- How can I detect if the external image does not exist in the source url to manage and prevent the image to be shown on my site? Is there any option in RemoteReader?

**Edit:** I've also tested `RemoteReaderPlugin.Current.FileExists` method, but it always returns `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Making a short URL means storing the long URL in a database. Databases are slow, and add a point of failure. That's why we constantly see broken shortlinks all over the web.

You can use `Config.Current.Rewrite` to implement your own shortlinks. But it will be slower (network latency), reduce scalability, and images will be broken if your database isn't having a good day.

2) Just make an [HTTP HEAD request to see if it exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924679/c-sharp-how-can-i-check-if-a-url-exists-is-valid). Remember, HTTP requests are slow. Doing this during an image request will make it up to twice as slow. Doing it during page rendering for every image will be really slow. Try to do this when you acquire the URL initially and cache the result - if you can. It's not a good idea to do this on-the-fly.

RemoteReaderPlugin.Current.FileExists only detects if the path is in the remote URL syntax. It doesn't actually check for existence with an HTTP request (see #2).