# Checking if URL exists doesn't work

Tags: .net, vb.net, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I've got a function that's *SUPPOSED* to check if an url exists.

```
Function URLExists(URL As String) As Boolean
Dim HttpWebRequest_ As HttpWebRequest = WebRequest.Create(URL)
HttpWebRequest_.Method="HEAD" 'It doesn't work even without this.
Dim HttpWebResponse_ As HttpWebResponse = HttpWebRequest_.GetResponse()
Return HttpWebResponse_.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK
End Function
```

If I try URLExists("http://www.google.com/thisPageDoesNotExistAndIsRetarded.html"), it returns True, and if I try URLExists("https://www.google.com/"), (which obviously exists), it returns True, (correct). Thanks.

Comment: @nhgrif What's wrong with = HttpStatusCode.OK

Comment: The http request succeed because the 404 is managed by google. Try with something like `"https://www.ObviouslyNotARegistredUrl.com/"`

Comment: @Zirkonix How do I check if the URL doesn't exist on google.

Comment: [See this answer from a similar post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/924682/2188407)

Comment: @Zirkonix They use Try.Catch. Mine never throws and exception.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with VB, but I've write some c#:

```
string url = "http://www.google.com/thisPageDoesNotExistAndIsRetarded.html";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
request.Method = "HEAD";
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
```

And a `[System.Net.WebException]` (Error: 404) is thrown at runtime at the `GetResponse()`. 
It is working.

Perhaps you can try to add a `try{  } catch{ return false}` in your method.

Comment: It never throws an exception, coz, like u said, the 404 page is managed by goofle.

Comment: Well I was wrong. I tried it and it does throw a System.Net.WebException.