# how to know given website is https protected or not in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, http

how to Verify where website is using https, a secure communication protocol/not.
like if i give www.facebook.com it should show https protected or not.im getting error in second line.im getting false even though site is https

```
  checkSecured();

  private void checkSecured()
{
    string url = txturl.Text.Trim();
    var uri = new Uri("https://www.facebook.com");
    var requestType = uri.Scheme;
    var value= HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection;

        }
```

Comment: HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection

Comment: He ask how to find if a remote site is https, not the `Current` one.

Comment: i just want to detect a website is https protected or not. i will give any website name in text box it should tell protected or not. i dont know whether site having http or not. to make seo tool. general user give www.google.com then it should https protected or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are many sites which works on both http and https, some works on http and some on https.

So in your url check twice

1) If http://+url is valid or not

2) if https://+url is valid or not.

Then you can get the result.

```
private bool RemoteFileExists(string url)
{
try
{
    //Creating the HttpWebRequest
    HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url) as HttpWebRequest;
    //Setting the Request method HEAD, you can also use GET too.
    request.Method = "HEAD";
    //Getting the Web Response.
    HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
    //Returns TRUE if the Status code == 200
    response.Close();
    return (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
catch
{
    //Any exception will returns false.
    return false;
}
}
```

from: [C# How can I check if a URL exists/is valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924679/c-sharp-how-can-i-check-if-a-url-exists-is-valid)

Answer (score -2):

You can use the below line of code to check if the connection is secured or not.

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.IsSecureConnection
```

Comment: how to write a method to get that property. i didnt get it , can u help me out by creating sample method

Comment: In your question, the url is not in the correct format. if you want to create a Uri, you need to do the following.  
           Uri baseUri = new Uri("https://www.stackoverflow.com");
           string test = baseUri.Scheme;

You have to mention the scheme (http:// or https://)