# How do I check if a C# Uri object refers to an existing file?

Tags: c#, file, uri

If I instantiate a `Uri` that refers to a path where no file exists, I'd like it to throw an error but it doesn't. And nothing I do with such a `Uri` seems to throw an error either.

```
var bi = new BitmapImage(new Uri("vignette.png", UriKind.Relative));
```

Is there any way to get it to throw an error? Or is there a way to check if the file exists like with `File.Exists()` but using a `Uri` object instead of a `string`?

This is not a duplicate of [C# How can I check if a URL exists/is valid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924679/c-sharp-how-can-i-check-if-a-url-exists-is-valid) because my question pertains specifically to testing a C# `Uri` object. I'm already aware of how to check if a file exists using a string representation of its path.

Comment: Maybe this is what you're looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/924679/c-sharp-how-can-i-check-if-a-url-exists-is-valid

Comment: No, I'm talking about C# `Uri` objects. Not a single `Uri` object is mentioned in that question or any of its answers. This is not a duplicate. If that's still unclear, can someone help me make it clearer?

Comment: It's like Path. It just helps you build and mess around with URIs. It doesn't care if it exists.

Comment: So it can't be done?

Comment: This can be done by creating a lightweight class that implements implicit casts operators to/from string. Then call `File.Exists(...)` in the constructor. Here's an example from one of my personal libraries: https://github.com/austindrenski/AD.IO/blob/master/AD.IO/Paths/FilePath.cs