# Validate a URL before HTTP call

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

How do I validate a URL before I post a HttpClient.GetAsync call. I want to make sure I am calling a valid URL.

Comment: Could you please tag your question either [tag:.net] or [tag:.net-core] (not both) and add a tag for the language you are using? Also did you see this possible duplicate for C#/.NET? https://stackoverflow.com/q/924679/397817

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Uri.TryCreate to validate an URL:

```
public bool UrlValiator(string url)
{
    Uri validatedUrl;
    return Uri.TryCreate(url, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute, out validatedUrl);
}
```