# C# - Check if a URI that is within the network is valid

Tags: c#, api, asp.net-core

I found this code from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/924679/c-sharp-how-can-i-check-if-a-url-exists-is-valid) it works for uri like "https://google.com" but it doesn't work for something like "https://172.61.58.168/Account/Login/". I actually don't know why. I have an App using that URI that has an API that I need to call. I can successfully do an api-call and I just decided to make a validation first if the base uri exist and is valid.

Help. Thanks.

code:

```
bool isHttpValid = false;
try
{
    //Creating the HttpWebRequest
    HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("https://172.16.85.186/Account/Login/") as HttpWebRequest;
    //Setting the Request method HEAD, you can also use GET too.
    request.Method = "HEAD";
    //Getting the Web Response.
    HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
    //Returns TRUE if the Status code == 200
    response.Close();
    isHttpValid = true;
}
catch
{
    //Any exception will returns false.
    isHttpValid = false;
}
```

Comment: do a debug on the response code.

Comment: System.Net.WebException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

Comment: Well, you dont have any code to accept a certificate... that makes perfect sense

Comment: @JosephReyes Edit your question and put details there, not in comments.

Comment: @BugFinder What code should I add?

Comment: @JosephReyes The exception you posted there previously seems interesting. Post it with the question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should use `HttpClient` instead of `WebRequest`, then you are checking that a **HTTP** request is valid, however your using a **HTTPS URL**.

If you want a method that check both HTTP and HTTPS URLs, you have to think how are you going to manage HTTPS certificates, due to that exception:

> System.Net.WebException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure. ---> System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: The SSL connection could not be established, see inner exception. ---> System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: The remote certificate is invalid according to the validation procedure.

Maybe you want to add that custom certificate as secure, or you want to remove the security policy that checks the SSL certificates (I don't recommend it), following that other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12553277/allowing-untrusted-ssl-certificates-with-httpclient).

I hope this can help you.