# Download String From Address "http://www.last.fm/music/Boney%20M./+images"

Tags: c#, webclient, last.fm

I`m trying to download string from address "http://www.last.fm/music/Boney%20M./+images",but 
return null,

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
string html = webClient.DownloadString(new Uri("http://www.last.fm/music/Boney%20M./+images"));
```

Comment: When visiting with my browser, i think it redirected to `http://www.last.fm/music/Boney+M./+images` (notice the missing `%20`). I dont know how WebClient handles redirects but Try that new redirected address and see what happens.

Comment: @Moje I believe you're on to something. When executing the above in PowerShell I got `Exception calling "DownloadString" with "1" argument(s): "Too many automatic redirections were attempted."`. FWIW, replacing the space with a `+` doesn't seem to help either.

Comment: Possibly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/518181/too-many-automatic-redirections-were-attempted-error-message-when-using-a-http

Comment: Doesn't make sense here. The first redirect changes the space to a `+`. But if I retry with that address I'm getting *another* redirect to itself. I'm guessing it's looking for some headers and caught in a redirect loop since they are missing... I wonder why @OnoSendai got it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just tried it on a test application under VS2012 Express, and it's working as intended.

Some thoughts:

- The problem may lie in the fact that you are behind a proxy, and you may need to create a WebProxy object and provide your credentials.
- Sometimes (which is not the case, since it worked for me) sites expect some headers - for example HTTP_REFERER.